# How to get the type of a variable in a macro?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, macros

I'm currently using this code for a foreach macro:

```
#define foreach(T, arr, it) for(T::iterator it = (arr).begin(), itend = (arr).end(); it != itend; ++it)
```

How can i get rid of the first parameter `T` and make the compiler figure out which type it should copy/paste in the code `T::iterator` ? It seems rather silly i need to type it myself when it could be figured out from the variable itself.

Comment: `It seems rather silly I need to type it myself` It seems even sillier to me that you're trying to create a macro like this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot do anything that's specifically related to the macro. Macros are not type templates; they are macros. They exist before any concept of "types" is introduced into the build phases.

Comment: It only seems "silly" to you because you are apparently used to high-level languages -- which, incidentally, are _built on_ languages like C++. If you want high-level, go high-level. Otherwise, accept that you are programming one stage away from assembly and take as read the verbosity that goes with it.

Comment: @Tomalak you just summarized my feelings about many things.

Comment: @tomalak, perhaps that is true. however, is there any ways of doing this, if not using macros at all, but templates somehow perhaps?

Comment: @Rookie if you didn't mind writing functions for each of your loop bodies, you can do something like this: http://codepad.org/IS0hdV5T but then you're reinvented `std::for_each` :)

Comment: @Rookie: Take a look at Boost.Foreach.

Comment: @seth, im aware of std::for_each, its even worser actually, lots more typing there and it doesnt quite well work the way i want it to work, because its calling a function in the third parameter, thats approximately 18.2 times worse way of doing it... i dont know why anyone would want to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is pre `auto` and `decltype`, your best bet is using [Eric Niebler's `FOREACH` macro](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html).

Or upgrade your compiler to VC 2010 and just use `auto`.

Comment: Hah, he even left a reference to `BOOST_FOREACH` in one of his code samples. "Eric Niebler's `FOREACH` macro" my frakking ass; thief.

Comment: @Tomalak, I think he wrote `BOOST_FOREACH`. His name is in the copyright for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a compiler capable of C++11 you can use `auto`:

```
#define foreach(arr, it) for(auto it = (arr).begin(), itend = (arr).end(); it != itend; ++it)
```

Comment: i guess i dont have support for the keyword `auto` even though it highlights as blue in visual studio 2008. i get errors `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int` and `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator' to 'int'` at that macro line. isnt there any other way for this?

Comment: @Rookie: `auto` has a different meaning in C++03 (which is what VS2008's version of `auto` is). VS2010 supports the C++11 meaning of `auto`.

Comment: @Rookie have you considered upgrading? :)

Comment: <nitpick>C++11 does not exist until publication!</nitpick>

Comment: @seth, i tried upgrade to 2010 but it keeps crashing and so forth, i simply **cant** use it. not to mention its super laggy for me.

Comment: @Rookie: You can download the VC++2010 compiler itself via [the latest Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924). The compiler is separate from the IDE. It's possible to run the VC++2010 compiler in VS2008.

Comment: @In silico good point, I had forgot about that, and I'd add that the reverse is also possible. Rookie, if you don't upgrade compilers, you can't do what you're wanting.

Comment: @In silico, nice, i had no idea that is possible! i will try to upgrade. thanks.